# How to copy Anonymous variable data to datatable in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-3.0

I want to copy the records i get in the Anonymous variable into datatable .How can it be done ?
What i am doing is fetching the records from the datatable1 and keeping it in Anonymous variable and now what i want is that to copy the fetched records into datatable2 .

Code i am using is:

```
var query = from t in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                   select new
                   {
                       Name= t.Field<string>("Name"),
                       Age = t.Field<int>("Age")
                   };
```

But when i use

```
DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();
datatable2 = query.copytodatatable(); //Error here
```

How to move query records to datatatable2 ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just try to do it like that...

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

            var query =
                from t in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                               select new
                               {
                                   Name= t.Field<string>("Name"),
                                   Age = t.Field<int>("Age")
                               };


        dt = query.CopyToDataTable();


OR..

instead of this dt = query.CopyToDataTable(); you can use

 foreach (var item in query ) 
            {   
                dt.Rows.Add(item.Name,item.Age);                 
            }
```

Comment: @Agarwal,No its not working . Its giving me a casting error that, cannot implicitly convert a Anonymous type to datatable are you missing a cast?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct method to populate DataTable with Anonymous variable :

```
DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();
datatable2 = query.copytodatatable(); //Error here
```

To populate DataTable with Anonymous variable check the below code:

```
    // your query
    var query = from t in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           Name= t.Field<string>("Name"),
                           Age = t.Field<int>("Age")
                       };

// design table first
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn
    {
        ColumnName = "YourColumnName",
        DataType = typeof(String);
    });
...

List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (var t in query)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row.SetField<string>("YourColumnName", t.Name); // extension method from System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
    ...

    list.Add(row);
}

DataTable table = list.CopyToDataTable(); // extension method too
```

Or more LINQ way:

```
query
    .Select(t =>
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            ...
            return row;
        })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Or in same query syntax. Implement a method:

```
static DataRow NewRow(DataRow row, string Name, ....)
{
    ...
}
```

Then query itself:

```
(from ...
 where ...
 select NewRow(table.NewRow(), t.Name, ...)
).CopyToDataTable();
```

Other Option you can use is :

Call `.ToList()`
The resulting `List<T>` can also be bound to a `DataTable`